# Mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary' in QtCreator with Qt 5.11 and Crypto++

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-creator, crypto++

I'm trying to build my project, which combines Qt 5.11 and CryptoPP 7.0.0 .
I also need to build it statically. So I configured Qt with :

```
configure -release -opensource -platform win32-msvc2017 -static -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

This gives me all Qt libs under `qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\build_static\lib`

QtCreator builds Qt code successfully with this kit, and the generated binary can run without Qt DLLs, so I assume everything is right here.

On the other hand, I picked up CryptoPP sources, opened .sln file, set the /MT flag, then I have a `cryptlib.lib` under `cryptopp700\x64\Output\Release\`.

My Crypto++ code builds successfully, and again, generated binary executes without the need of any DLL.

Now I want to compile a code that combine both libraries, I chose QtCreator.
I added these lines to my `.pro` file :

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE = -MT
CONFIG += static
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../cryptopp700
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../cryptopp700
LIBS += $$PWD/../cryptopp700/x64/Output/Release/cryptlib.lib
```

QMake ran without error, but, at compile time, I get hundreds of errors like:

```
LNK 2038 : mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary' : MD_DynamicRelease 
doesn't match with 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
```

And this for every Qt .lib file.

The last thing I tried is to modify qmake.conf under `qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\build_static\mkspecs\win32-msvc\qmake.conf` by setting :

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += /MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS         += /MT
```

but that didn't solve anything.
It seems that one of the 2 libraries aren't statically built, but since they are, I don't know where to search now...

Comment: Maybe [Visual Studio | Runtime Linking](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Visual_Studio#Runtime_Linking) will be helpful. If you already changed the setting for the Crypto++ library, then maybe you need to perform a *"Clean All"* and rebuild Crypto++.

Comment: Well, the problem was on Qt side ! It seems that adding `-static` to `configure` isn't enough for static building (at least with MSVC), I had to replace every -MD by -MT and -MDd by -MTd in `Qt_folder\qtbase\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf`. After cleaning leftovers from previous build, it worked !

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer.